# i am getting while running on my mobile. But it is running fine on ionic serve

Tags: ionic4

Getting ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED error. I have tried every thing change my config.xml , network_config getting update automatically when i add my domain. ionic cli is 5.4.13

```
        <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
        <widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
            <name>MyApp</name>
            <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
            <author email="hi@ionicframework.com" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
            <content src="index.html" />
            <access origin="*" />
            <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
            <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
            <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
            <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
            <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
            <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
            <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
            <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
            <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
            <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
            <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
            <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
            <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
            <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
            <platform name="android">
                <access origin="*" />
                <preference name="android-usesCleartextTraffic" value="true" />
                <allow-navigation href="*" />
                <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
                    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
                    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
                </edit-config>
                <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
                <allow-intent href="market:*" />


            </platform>

        </widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ionic cordova http plugin for network request your error maybe solve.

Here is link for that

```
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http
```